# AWS: How to make sure that Instance Profile is initialized and propagized when starting the ec2 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am starting servers using a ec2 instance profile with instance profiles.

The problem is the Profile sometimes is not "there" after creating it, even if I wait like 10 seconds:

```
  # Create new Instance Profile
  instanceProfile = self.iam.create_instance_profile(InstanceProfileName=instProfName)
  instanceProfile.add_role(RoleName="...")

  time.sleep(10)

  # Create the Instance
  instances = self.ec2.create_instances(
     # ...
     IamInstanceProfile={
        "Name":instanceProfile.instance_profile_name
     }
  )
```

is there a way to wait for it to be propagated?

My first attempt is:

```
  error = 30
  dryRun = True

  while error > 0:
     try:
        # Create the Instance
        instances = self.ec2.create_instances(
           DryRun=dryRun
           # ...               
           IamInstanceProfile={
              "Name":instanceProfile.instance_profile_name
           }
        )
        if not dryRun:
           break;

        dryRun = False

     except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        error = error - 1;
```

but how do I get only the IAM Profile error?

Answer (score 0):

Much of AWS works using "eventual consistency". That means that after you make a change, it will take some time to propagate through the system.

After you create the instance profile:

1. Delay by 5 or 10 seconds (or some other time you're comfortable with),
2. Call `iam.get_instance_profile` with your instance profile name.
3. Repeat delay and check until `get_instance_profile` returns your information.

Another thing you can do is catch the "instance profile not found error" during the `ec2.create_instances` call, and delay and repeat it if you get that error.

Comment: how do I catch an error that only is a "ClientError" ?

Comment: You'll nee to examine `e` to see if there are any distinguishing data. Otherwise, you'll just need to reattempt on any such error.

Comment: hmm... the problem is I cannot examine `e` without actually trying to start an instance

Comment: Unfortunately, I had to go with the first option eventually - checking if `iam.get_instance_profile` returns a value did not necessarily mean that EC2 was able to access that value. Feels really hacky and like it's going to break, but oh well.